# Select Top 1 field and assign to local variable where database name is dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server

When executing below sql server i am unable to pass @AKM parameter in the code how ever i am able to reproduce the same which doing in simple query's. However i am able to pass variable for id as it is an int type but @akm is in charecter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_akm_test]
    @AKM NVARCHAR(128), 
    @Anlsid Int
    AS 
    DECLARE @Sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @type NVARCHAR(MAX);
    BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @type= sample_type FROM ' + @RDM +'.dbo.analysis where ID= '@id
        PRINT(@type)
            IF (@type = 8017)
            BEGIN 
            SET @Sql1 = N'select sample_n FROM'+ QUOTENAME(@AKM) +'..sample'
            END
            ELSE
            Begin
            SET @Sql1 = N'select sampleid FROM'+ QUOTENAME(@AKM) +'..sample'
            END
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql1
    END
```

Comment: Any reason you tagged this with MySQL?

Comment: @DavidG i am working with MySQL

Comment: No, you're really not, you're working with SQL Server if the code you show actually works. If you're not sure which database technology you're working with, then perhaps you need to take a step back and doing some basic learning/tutorials?

Comment: @DavidG sorry you are right i am using sql only apologies..

Comment: You might take a peek at this and consider a different prefix for your procedures, or even better no prefix at all. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this

```
declare @RDM sysname = ???? -- pass the db name, missing in your code
declare @sql nvarchar(4000)= '',@type int

set @sql = '
SELECT TOP 1 @type= sample_type FROM ' + quotename(@RDM) +'.dbo.rdm_analysis where ID=110'

exec sp_executesql @sql,N'@type int output',@type = @type output

SET @Sql1 = '
select case when @type = 8017 then sample_n else sampleid end 
FROM'+ QUOTENAME(@AKM) +'..sample'

exec sp_executesql @sql1,N'@type int',@type
```

Comment: I am getting following error  "Cannot use the OUTPUT option when passing a constant to a stored procedure"